# Homebrew - where do you recommend placing your applications?

Tags: homebrew

I have just installed Homebrew, which has set-up the `/usr/local` folder structure. Is there a suggested location that I should be placing my application code within this new structure (if not, where is recommended)?

Comment: What do you mean by *your* application code, are you writing new code for Homebrew?